# Drupal domain access auto create content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal's [domain access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) to create micro sites in a white label system. Is there a way of automatically creating nodes with default content for each site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [hook_domain_insert()](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/domain/domain.api.php/function/hook_domain_insert/7.3) this will give you the id of the domain that has just been created in the $domain array. Then you can create a node as follows:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_domain_insert($domain, $form_values = array()) {
$domain_id = $domain['domain_id'];

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'your_type';
$node->title = 'Your Title';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->domain_site = 0;
$node->domains[$domain_id] = $domain_id;

$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
}
```